# Objects value and object arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a web application in AngularJS. I am confused about references in JavaScript. When do changes on an object affect its references?

For example, I have a controller in my app. and I use that controller to upload files and keep file information in a factory.

```
   $scope.fileArray = [];
    ...
    ...
    uploadFiles(file){
         $scope.fileArray.push(file);
         ..
         ..
         //on success
         file.params = data["parameters"]; //an array of strings about file path and name
         ...
         ...
    }
```

In uploadFiles function, I push file object into fileArray. Then when I change or add new attributes to file object, I can see those changes in fileArray.

```
var fileInfo = {
    infoArray : $scope.fileArray
}

fileFactory.keepFileInfo(fileInfo);
```

then I keep that array in factory. But this time change on $scope.fileArray is not reflected in factory. What is the logic here?

**EDIT**

I was wrong. Change in controller object effects factory, too. I wrote this minimal application to see it clearly and in my application I must be making error some where else.

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('TestController', function($scope, TestFactory) {
    $scope.fileArray = [];

    var files = [];
    files[0] = {
        parameters : {
            name : 'file1.txt',
            path : "user/files"
        }
    }

    $scope.fileArray.push(files[0]);

    files[1] = {
        parameters : {
            name : 'file2.txt',
            path : "user/files"
        }
    }

    $scope.fileArray.push(files[1]);

    files[2] = {
        parameters : {
            name : 'file3.txt',
            path : "user/files"
        }
    }

    $scope.fileArray.push(files[2]);

    TestFactory.setFileArray($scope.fileArray);

    files[0].parameters["name"] = "changed file name";

    console.log($scope.fileArray); //here writes "changed file name"    
    console.log(TestFactory.getFileArray()); //here writes "changed file name", too
});


testApp.factory('TestFactory', function() {
    var factory = {};

    var fileArray = [];

    factory.setFileArray = function(files) {
        fileArray = files;
    }

    factory.getFileArray = function() {
        return fileArray;
    }

    return factory;
});
```

Comment: Please show all relevant code. It does not seem you are sharing the factory array in controller if you define it with `$scope` since there is no $scope in factory

Answer (score -1):

Let's consider the following example:

```
var a = {};
var b = {c: a};
console.log(a === b.c);
a.d = {};
console.log(b.c);
```

If you have an object variable and you assign the member of another object to it, then they have the very same reference, so if you change either one, the other one will be changed as well. The same is the case if you do this with arrays:

```
var a = {};
var b = [a];
console.log(a === b[0]);
a.d = {};
console.log(b[0]);
```

Comment: Great but how does this tie into OP's factory and controller?

Comment: @charlietfl, good question. As long as he gives us more information, my answer will be edited. Up until then I can only help with general information.

Comment: Yes, but *general information* belongs to the comments section of a question. If the question wasn't clear enough for you don't hesitate to use the comments section under the question to ask for clarifications. Make sure you are using the answers section only if you are, well, answering a question.